# Closing info window with onclick javascript google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm trying to do something very simple, but searches have come up empty and for some reason I cannot solve this (I'm a JS beginner). I am trying to close an infowindow with onclick in an  tag. I know you can close it by clicking the "x" but the purpose of this is deeper.

My code:

```
function placeMarker(location) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<a href='#' id='link' onclick='infowindow.close()'>Close</a>"
  });
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
}
```

Is something like this possible? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you may have multiple infoWindow-instances(with your current code this will happen when you call the function multiple times):

You'll need to use a Node instead of a string as `content`. When you do so, you'll be able to use a reference to the infowindow from within the function(a closure) and assign the click-function using `addDomListener`:

```
function placeMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: location,
               map: map,
             }),
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
        content    = document.createElement('a');

    content.setAttribute('href','#');
    content.appendChild(document.createTextNode('close'));
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(content,'click',
                                     function(){infowindow.close();})
    infowindow.setContent(content);
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes your implementation will work as you have it listed assuming that:

1. You use a single common infowindow
2. The `infowindow` variable is global (defined outside of any function)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a close link like the one you have `onclick='infowindow.close()`. The InfoWindow object already has a 'close' icon. **X**

To make sure you only have one InfoWindow open at any given time, make it a single global object and open with the associated marker as parameter:

```
//Global
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
```

and then...

```
function placeMarker(location) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
  });
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    position: location,
    content: "Hello from this marker"
  });
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
 }
```

Comment: The OP specifically mentioned that the X close icon wasn't sufficient.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth, I saw that, but I couldn't imagine what the "deeper" purpose may be. :-)